# How to run Windows command in chain

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I found the bat file from here:

http://www.dostips.com/DtCodeBatchFiles.php#Batch.FindAndReplace

I want to run another command after this bat, but it doesn't work. I guess there must be something wrong the the code the site provides. Anyone can give me a clue?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can chain commands in dos using the && for example

```
echo hello&&echo world
```

Comment: If the first commands fails, the second command will not run, it seems. I tried `rmdir "C:\Python"&&mklink /J "C:\Python" "C:\Python26"` and if the directory didn't first exist, it would throw an error and abort. I changed it to `rmdir "C:\Python"|mklink /J "C:\Python" "C:\Python26"` and it works how I want, but it seems "wrong" to use pipe  in this manner. So, for you, it looks like `type in.txt|BatchSubstitute.bat "text to replace" "text to put" > out.txt` for files in.txt and out.txt would be what to use? Note pipe is `|` (pipe char) not `I` (capital I char).

Comment: @MarkRibau: Perhaps use the logical or, i.e.: `echo hello||echo world`?

Comment: @Protectorone Logical or does indeed work. It totally didn't occur to me to do that. However, it does print out that the first command failed, while with the pipe it doesn't. I suppose it primarily depends on what I want users of the script to see. And they'd only see it the first time.

Answer (score 14):

As per Microsoft Support:

> This behavior occurs because the && command separator performs error
> checking. If the command to the left of the && command does not return
> the expected results, the commands to the right of the && command do
> not run.

And

> When you use a single & command, error checking is not performed and
> all commands run.

You can check here:

[Using multiple commands and conditional processing symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-xp/bb490954(v=technet.10)#using-multiple-commands-and-conditional-processing-symbols)

[Multiple Commands on a Single Line May Not Run When You Use the && Command Separator (archived page)](https://web.archive.org/web/20201020161709/https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/279253)

[Original link - No longer exists](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/279253)